A manifold with an almost-complex structure that admits a holomorphic frame is integrable
Let $(M,I)$ be an almost-complex manifold such that every point $m\in M$ has a neighborhood $U\ni m$ and holomorphic functions $f_1, \dots, f_n:U\to\mathbb C$ such that $\text{span}(df_1(m), \dots, df_n(m))=\Lambda^{1,0}_m(M)$. I want to prove that the almost-complex structure $I$ is integrable.
One way to do that is to realize that the condition that the differentials generate the entire space of holomorphic forms is open (it looks like $\det(\cdots)\neq 0$), so in a possibly smaller open set $V\ni p$ we have $\text{span}(df_1, \dots, df_n)=\Lambda^{1,0}(V)$. So we can define a chart
\begin{align}
\varphi: V&\to\mathbb C^n\\
p&\mapsto (f_1(p), \dots, f_n(p)).
\end{align}
And verify that for two charts defined this way $\varphi\circ \psi^{-1}$ is holomorphic by using that the differential of $\varphi$ is invertible, the inverse function theorem and that the composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic. Thus the functions defined this way form a compatible biholomorphic atlas therefore $M$ has a complex manifold structure, and then we can verify that it is compatible with $I$.
But I'm almost sure this isn't the proof that the professor wanted. It's inelegant and uses a lot of previous results. In particular, we are defining integrability using sheaves, i.e. $(M, I)$ is integrable if the sheaf $\mathcal O=\{f:M\to \mathbb C : df\in\Lambda^{1,0}(M)\}$ makes $M$ locally isomorphic to $(U, \mathcal O_U)$ as ringed spaces where $U\subset\mathbb C^n$ is an open set and $\mathcal O_U$ is the sheaf of holomorhic functions on it. So the intended proof probably uses this definition.
Is there a proof without charts?

What about the Nijenhuis tensor? Also, what do you mean by a holomorphic frame?

@TedShifrin we don't have the Newlander-Niremberg theorem yet. The statement I need to prove is in the first paragraph. I just called it a holomorphic frame so it would fit in the title.

This is more of a coframe than a frame; that's why I asked. But if we don't know the structure is integrable, the use of the term "holomorphic function" is a bit troublesome.  I guess you mean that $\bar\partial f = 0$, but we do not know $\bar\partial^2 = 0$.

What’s stopping you from looking at this setup on a small ball with an almost complex structure you know not to be integrable and concluding that it is integrable?

@GunnarÞórMagnússon I think what stops you is something different for each $(m, I)$. Are you thinking of any specific examples?

You proof is in fact correct. $\mathcal O$ being locally isomorphic to $(U,\mathcal O_U)$ is the same as checking $\varphi^*\mathcal O_U=\mathcal O$, which is basically the definition of $\varphi=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$.
The only thing you need to be careful is that $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are merely differentiable (you can say they are "$J$-holomorphic" if you modify your question a bit) in the beginning. It is holomorphic exactly because we define the complex structure by taking pullback of $\Lambda^{0,1}(\mathbb C^n)$ under $\varphi$.
As a digression, in a more general setting, if you replace $\Lambda^{0,1}$ by any other cotangent subbundle $\mathcal S\subset\mathbb CTM$ which are differential closed, the assumption $Span(df_1,\dots,df_n)=\mathcal S$ can already be used to defined integrability. In the language of cochain complexes we say $\mathcal S$ is involutive if it is differental closed i.e. for every section $\alpha$ of $\mathcal S$, $d\alpha$ is a section of $\mathcal S\wedge\Lambda^1$; we say  $\mathcal S$ is integrable if it is differential exact if locally there are $f_1,\dots,f_r$ (where $r=\operatorname{rank}\mathcal S$) such that $Span(df_1,\dots,df_r)=\mathcal S$ in the domain.
